# Appending dataframes onto excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have read in an excel into a dataframe which looks like:

df =

```
Item   Questions     Answer
1      First name    Alex
1.1    Age           43
1.2    Nationality   English
etc....
```

I have many similar excel files such as these which i plan to read into dataframes, however i want to collate all of these in a separate excel. I don't want to include all the columns so for the above dataframe i would like it to look like the below once it's added onto the seperate excel:

```
First Name   Age   Nationality
Alex         43    English
```

Also, how would i add other similar dataframes onto this separate excel, i assume it would be using append but i'm not quite sure how to do it

Comment: create an empty dataframe and use a for loop to read all excel files and add the required fields to empty dataframe

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to loop through each of your excel tables (read them in) and first pivot or transpose the dataframe to get the column format you want (there are various ways to do this) and then concatenate it to a separate, single dataframe:

```
total_dataframe = pd.DataFrame() #initialize empty table

for file in my_excel_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(file) 
    df = pd.DataFrame(df.values.T) #transpose the table
    headers = df.iloc[0] #Make first row the column headers
    new_df = pd.DataFrame(df.values[1:], columns=headers)
    total_dataframe = pd.concat([total_dataframe, new_df]) #append to final table
```

There are certainly more elegant ways to do this, but I think this breaks down the process pretty clearly.